# Python script to get top visited websites in a browser

Tags: python, django, browser

i want to get the list of top 10 visted websites in a browser using python script. 
 Am guessing there is a way to fetch all the visited websites from a particular browser and list the top 10 ones in a for loop or any other possible and relevant way.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need django for that. According to the browser you're using, you can write a plugin which counts the number time you've been on a website. The algorithim is quite simple (pseudo code):

```
websites = {}
if current_website not in websites:
    websites[current_website] = 1
else
    websites[current_webisite] += 1
```

Something like this ... hope it helped though.